# ListView Header and ItemTemplate cant left align

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, winui-3, winui

ListViews Header & ItemTemplate have same column widths but headers after the `*` column are right aligned:

[image]

The header (yellow BG) is showing the column widths, `* 70 15 & 70`
The `*` aligns to the left but the others seem to align to the right.
We want the `70` text to be above the `D` of Data, ie aligned to the left.

How can we achieve this?

[Here](https://github.com/tinmac/ListViewTest) is a basic github project to show the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` is not designed to be used with columns. You should use the **CommunityToolkit** [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid) instead.

```xml
<toolkit:DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemsOC, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn
            Width="*"
            Header="*">
            <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Border
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Background="Orange"
                            CornerRadius="8">
                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="0,1,6,3"
                                FontSize="10"
                                FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                Foreground="#000"
                                Text="{Binding Data_0}" />
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
            Width="70"
            Binding="{Binding Data_1}"
            Header="70" />
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
            Width="70"
            Binding="{Binding Data_2}"
            Header="70" />
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn
            Width="70"
            Binding="{Binding Data_3}"
            Header="70" />
    </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Did you get to solve your issue?